# how can i get iPhone digital certificate?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, digital-signature

do u know which URL for getting iphone digital certificate . i don't the rules for get?
Seeking some link they told $99 paid. But where? what rules ? nothing see . So Could u refer correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to register at http://developer.apple.com/programs/iphone/ and once you're accepted you'll be able to add devices and request certificates. If you're just wanting to get start with iPhone development you can download the SDK from http://developer.apple.com/iphone/ and run your code in the simulator.

The $99 enrolment only needs to be done once you're ready to test on a device or want to deploy to the iTunes AppStore